# Android Photoview move relative views with zoom

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have the following layout with a ViewPager that basically cycles through various Images.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imagePager_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <PhotoView
                android:id="@+id/imagePager_imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imagePager_textTitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="TITLE"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imagePager_imageView"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imagePager_titleLine"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/imagePager_textTitle"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                   android:paddingRight="5dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/linebig"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imagePager_textSubtitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SUBTITLE"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imagePager_titleLine"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imagePager_subtitleLine"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/imagePager_textSubtitle"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                   android:paddingRight="30dp"
                   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/linebig"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imagePager_textContent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="CONTENT"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imagePager_subtitleLine"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

From what you can see below the image I aslo have some views that are some sort of a description. The things I am trying to achieve are the following.

1. When the image appears I want it zoomed out to screen width
2. Obviously certain images will be longer then the screen height and will push the description down, so I want to be able to scroll. That's why I'm using scrollview.
3. Most importantly I want to zoom in and out the image, and when I do that I want the description to move accordingly.

My ImageAdapter is the following (included only the relevant methods):

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View layout = null;

        if (container.getContext() != null) {

            //load imagepager layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_pager, container, false);

            if (layout != null) {

                //Fill in textviews

                //get current bitmap depending on viewpager position
                //Bitmap is saved as byte[] in container
                int imageNumber = getImageNumber(position);
                BitmapContainer bitmap = getBitmap(imageNumber);

                //create imageview
                setImageview(layout, bitmap);

                container.addView(layout, ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            }
        }
        return layout;
    }

    private void setImageview(View layout, BitmapContainer container) { 
        PhotoView iv = (PhotoView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imagePager_imageView);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(container.getImage(), 0,
                    container.getImage().length);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the bitmap does not also resize it's imageview and the textviews below remain still.

Comment: I think you should use different library in order to make those things happen.